# If I disable the list items to display in search results, will it have any impact on indexing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, threshold, indexed-column

I am having a SharePoint list with 30 columns. I have added few columns to the "Indexed Columns". But I don't want to display any list item in the search results. So I want to disable following option. 
[image]

If I disable above option, will it have any impact on Indexed columns. I mean will there be any exceptions if I use the indexed columns in my queries (REST, CSOM) etc. like threshold error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a correlation between indexed columns and search results. You don't need to have Search Service Application provisioned and you can still have indexed columns set up on your list.

Comment: Thanks. May be I am wrong, Is there any article which can describe this?

Comment: This is the official MS documentation for adding indexed columns: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0. If there was a prerequisite for indexed columns I am sure they would at least put a note.

Comment: Yes I have already referred to the same article earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Indexed columns are actually implemented by populating all values of the indexed columns into the NameValuePair table and that table is then joined with the AllUserData table once a query is executed that uses the indexed column as a filter. They are not stored in the search index.

Reference: [SharePoint 2010–Indexing columns in a SharePoint List](http://iedaddy.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010indexing-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/)